# Repeat values from table 1 for each value in table 2

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables:

[image]

and

[image]

I'm trying to create the following output:

[image]

How can I do this considering there's nothing to join on? Both of these initial tables are coming from SQL queries and are not a sequence. Using MSSQL.

Comment: Do a CROSS JOIN, i.e. without join condition!

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it's not code (:

Comment: If I want to setup a test with your sample data I can't copy your test data. I have to manually type it by reading your image. Plus, did you see "*Images are often blocked by corporate proxies*" which means that a lot of people can not even see your sample data.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name good point, noted for next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use cross join by 2 ways

```
SELECT Number,Letter FROM Table1,Table2
```

Or

```
SELECT Number,Letter FROM Table1 CROSS JOIN Table2
```

Demo

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/157e3/3